# sql view with hebrew column names errors

Tags: c#, sql, view, sql-server-2008-r2, hebrew

i use C# to display sql view in datagridview
i have the following view with hebrew for column names

```
CREATE VIEW [fixes_view]
AS
  SELECT f.fixId        AS N'מס תיקון',
         f.receiveDate  AS N'ת.קבלה',
         c.clientName   AS N'שם לקוח',
         m.modelName    AS N'דגם',
         f.problem      AS N'תיאור תקלה',
         f.comments     AS N'הערות',
         e.employeeName AS N'שם עובד',
         f.priceOffer   AS N'מחיר ראשונ',
         f.price        AS N'מחיר סופי',
         f.returned     AS N'הוחזר'
  FROM   fixes f
         INNER JOIN clients c
                 ON f.clientId = c.clientId
         INNER JOIN modelist m
                 ON f.modelID = m.modelID
         INNER JOIN employees e
                 ON f.employeeId = e.employeeId
```

when i want to use it in C# and call it with another condition using

```
        public DataTable GetAllActiveFixTable()
    {
        return genericGetFixTable("WHERE returned=0;");
    }
```

i tried to refer to the "AS" name 'הוחזר' but it gives me an error when i call it

error:

> Invalid column name 'returned'.

```
private DataTable genericGetFixTable (string str)
    {
        return genericGetTable("select * FROM [fixes_view] " + str);

    }


create table fixes (
fixId int IDENTITY(1,1) primary key,
receiveDate date not null,
clientId int not null,
modelID int not null,
problem nvarchar(100) not null,
comments nvarchar(50),
employeeId int not null,
priceOffer real,
price real,
returned bit,
foreign key (clientId)
references clients,
foreign key (modelID)
references modelist,
foreign key (employeeId)
references employees)
```

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, show the actual code that is failing.

Comment: You should paste in the error.

Comment: Do not use the old style of join. Use proper `inner join` which is more readable

Comment: @GordonLinoff added, MS SQL 2008 R2

Comment: @NoDisplayName changed to INNER JOIN

Comment: Looks like error is not due to the alias name. Do you have column named `returned` in `fixes` table

Comment: @NoDisplayName yes, added the fixes table code

Comment: can't replicate the error check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e95a1/1

Comment: @NoDisplayName it shows me the table just can't add the returned

Comment: ok, i can fix it if i name returned in english